# Why `cordova build android` always downloads android-25 platform

Tags: android, cordova, docker, continuous-integration

Even when I have :

- Specify `minSdkVersion=19` in `config.xml`
- Specify via gradle parameter `--gradleArg=-PcdvminSdkVersion=19`
- Specify `target=android-19` in `platform/android/project.properties` (I know, I shouldn't do this)

No matter which order I did the above, the build process always downloads android-25...

```
....
File /root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 25 in /opt/android-sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 25 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 25".
"Install Android SDK Platform 25" ready.
Finishing "Install Android SDK Platform 25"
Installing Android SDK Platform 25 in /opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-25
"Install Android SDK Platform 25" complete.
...
```

Here's my situation

```
~# cordova -v
7.0.1

~# cordova platform version android
Installed platforms:
  android 6.2.3
Available platforms:
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0 (deprecated)
  browser ~4.1.0
  webos ~3.7.0
  windows ~5.0.0
```

Did I miss something?

I'm running the build inside container for a CI purposes. So unintended/unforeseen dependency resolution must be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: Did u check ur emulator version ?

Comment: @Madpop I'm trying to build projects not running them. Running is whole other exercise for now.

Comment: Yeah i understood your issue just set your android emulator version to working sdk or what ever the sdk u want and then build it it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your config.xml you would have a line

```
<engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3"/>
```

This forces the Cordova Android build to download only android-25 everytime.

Comment: I do have that entry in config.xml, `cordova plaform add android` puts it there. So I take it that android-25 will always being pulled no matter what because it's the latest version cordova-android 6.x.x can support?

Comment: Cordova's latest Android package supports up to Android API Level 25. So latest version is fetched everytime based on the mapping below.

cordova-android Version  -  Android API-Levels
6.X.X  -  16 - 25 |  5.X.X   -  14 - 23 |  4.1.X  -  14 - 22  |  4.0.X  -  10 - 22  |  3.7.X  -  10 - 21